# Article buddy text encryption or something else?

Tags: seo, search-engine

I tried out "article buddy" (http://article-buddy.com/sales-page/)

They claim to change any content into original content for the search engines.
Everytime I tested  the output of the tool it passed copyscrape and such.

After a while I tried finding out how the tool was fooling the tests because the text did not seem to change in any way. After I pasted the so called original content into "textpad" (text editor). I saw a lot of weird characters especially the question mark that replaced certain characters in the text.

**Example (original text):**

WestBow Press titles are regularly reviewed by Thomas Nelson & Zondervan for new, talented authors. While there is no guarantee of the number of titles to be signed each year, this is an opportunity to get your foot in the door. - See more at:

**Example (output text of article buddy):**

W??tB?w Pr??? t?tl?? are regularly r?v??w?d b? Th?m?? N?l??n & Z?nd?rv?n for n?w, t?l?nt?d authors. Wh?l? th?r? ?? n? gu?r?nt?? ?f th? numb?r ?f t?tl?? t? b? ??gn?d each ???r, th?? ?? an opportunity t? g?t ??ur f??t ?n th? door. - S?? m?r? ?t:

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: We aren't support for article-buddy.  If they suck, you need to bug them and ask them why they suck.  And, if they have something on their website pointing you here for support, they're liars.  StackOverflow is for programming questions *only*.  Tell them to cut it out after you tell them to stop sucking :|

Comment: Maybe I wrote my story wrong but I'm not asking for any support or whatsoever. I'm just curious why the text looks so different in a text editor but looks exactly the same as the original content when pasting it on a website.

Comment: That has nothing to do with programming.  [This stuff.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen multiple tools like this one in the past. Typically, the way it works is that it spins the content and replace words or whole sentences.

This used to work back in the days. My suggestion is to not waist your time and money on those. The only acceptable thing these days is original content.